# Trouble with FloatField entry in Flask Application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I created a very simple flask crud where I should be able to introduce some Float Values, then here I have my model, Form and Route from where I try to save the data:

```
    class Paciente(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        nombres = db.Column(db.String(40),unique=True, nullable=False)
        apellidos = db.Column(db.String(40),unique=True, nullable=False)
        fecha_nacimiento = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False)
        semanas_gestacion = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
        soplo_cardiaco = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
        peso = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
        satO2_miembroSup = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
        satO2_miembroSup24 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
        satO2_miembroSup72 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
        satO2_miembroInf = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
        satO2_miembroInf24 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)


    class PacienteForm(FlaskForm):
        nombres = StringField('Nombres',validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
        apellidos = StringField('Apellidos',validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=30)])
        fecha_nacimiento = DateField('Fecha de nacimiento', format='%Y-%m-%d')
        semanas_gestacion = IntegerField('Semanas de gestacion',widget=NumberInput(),validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=1, max=2), NumberRange(min=0, max=50, message="Valores de 0 a 50")])
        soplo_cardiaco = SelectField('Soplo cardíaco',
                           choices=[
                               (1, 'Si'),
                               (0, 'No')])
        peso = FloatField('peso',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
            validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
        satO2_miembroSup = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 -  miembro superior al nacimiento',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
            validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
        satO2_miembroSup24 = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 - miembro superior al nacimiento 24 horas',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
            validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
        satO2_miembroSup72 = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 - miembro superior al nacimiento 72 horas',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
            validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
        satO2_miembroInf = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 - miembro inferior al nacimiento',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
            validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
        satO2_miembroInf24 = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 - miembro inferior al nacimiento  24 horas',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
            validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])


    def paciente():
        form = PacienteForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            pacientes = Paciente(nombres=form.nombres.data, apellidos=form.apellidos.data,
                                 fecha_nacimiento=form.fecha_nacimiento.data, semanas_gestacion=form.semanas_gestacion.data,
                                 soplo_cardiaco=form.soplo_cardiaco.data, peso=form.peso.data,
                                 satO2_miembroSu=form.satO2_miembroSu.data, satO2_miembroSup24=form.satO2_miembroSup24.data,
                                 satO2_miembroSup72=form.satO2_miembroSup72.data,
                                 satO2_miembroInf=form.satO2_miembroInf.data,
                                 satO2_miembroInf24=form.satO2_miembroInf24.data,
 author=current_user)
            db.session.add(pacientes)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Paciente creado','success')
            return redirect(url_for('dash'))
        return render_template('create_patient.html', title='Nuevo paciente', form=form)
```

But when i try to save something i get this error:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? I would really appreciate some help with this! Thank you very much guys in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over here you declare an IntegerField:

```
semanas_gestacion = IntegerField(
    'Semanas de gestacion',
     widget=NumberInput(), 
     validators=[
         InputRequired(), 
         Length(min=1, max=2), 
         NumberRange(min=0, max=50, message="Valores de 0 a 50")
      ]
)
```

However, one of you validators, the `Length` one, is invalid for your `Integerfield`, because an integer doesn't have a length. The string `"142"` has length 3, but this does not apply for the integer `142`, which doesn't have one.

You can solve your proplem by simply removing the `Length(min=1, max=2)` argument, and just rely on the `NumberRange(min=0, max=50)` argument.